# Ignoring files based on project folder name

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project set up to act as a template for new project within a git repository, and I want to setup my .gitignore to ignore a folder within the template project, but not for any new projects that are cloned from the template.

I thought that I could do this by specifying the project folder name in the .gitignore, but this doesn't seem to work.

(eg adding the line "template-project/web/app/themes/basetheme" in the .gitignore would ignore the basetheme folder ONLY if the project is contained within a folder called "template-project")

Has anyone successfully done anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a **[global `.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore)** file to hold system-wide rules, then you can use the specific project directory in the path.